# pyad module has no attribute aduser

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory

I have created a simple python file to get AD user details

```
    import pyad
    import pyad.adquery
    user1="userID"
    pyad.pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server="LDAPDOMAINNAME", username="USERID", password="PASSWORD")
    user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.from_cn(user1)
    print(user)
```

I am using Python 3.7.4 on windows 10 , I am getting following error
 user = pyad.aduser.ADUser.from_cn(user1)
AttributeError: module 'pyad' has no attribute 'aduser'

Seems like, I am missing something basic here, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be related to your import(s).

Try the following:

```
import pyad
from pyad import aduser
user1="userID"
pyad.pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server="LDAPDOMAINNAME", username="USERID", password="PASSWORD")
user = aduser.ADUser.from_cn(user1)
print(user)
```